# Determine subsequence of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know the formal definition of a subsequence, but can't figure out how to find them for some particular sequence. Could someone show some of the methods for finding them?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: If you want any help you need to be more specific! Please give an explicit example of something you find difficult.

Answer (score 4):

A subsequence is just some of the terms of the original sequence, kept in order.  If your original sequence is $1,2,3,4,5,6\dots $, one subsequence is $1,3,5,7,9 \dots $  Another is $1, 2343, 23565848, 8685845855858, \dots $  Finding a subsequence is easy.  Finding one that does what you want depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A subsequence is derived from the original sequence by removing elements, keeping the order.

One can remove finite or infinite many elements.

Valid edge cases are:

- remove all elements of the original sequence
- remove no element of the original sequence